# Network teaming VS bonding configuration

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, redhat-enterprise-linux, bonding

as I am understanding 
we can set on Linux configuration BONDING or network teaming

both approach support LAN fail over

for example

if on the server we have the following up link

```
eth1
eth2
```

in BOND when **eth1** is fail the **eth2** will take action

the same is on network teaming

so what should be the decision between - network teaming VS bonding configuration

Comment: Bonding/Teaming can do much more for you, than just failover: You can do link aggregation, path separation and more. If you just need failover, then use bonding: It is in the mainline kernel, well maintained and vendor neutral.

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically distribution like RedHat in its version 7 highly recommends to use Teaming over Bonding. Teaming have been redesigned with flexibility in mind, more features, and work great with network manager. I think it's better explained in the following link:

> https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2014/06/23/team-driver/

**Note:** RedHat (RHEL7) still support Bonding for backward compatibility but it's expected to be replaced by Teaming in later releases.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link is now redirected to [https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/if-you-bonding-you-will-love-teaming](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/if-you-bonding-you-will-love-teaming) which states:
Please note: teamd is deprecated in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 and is planned for removal in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 10.